# Programmatically click to change the current tab in UI-Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to activate the tabs programmatically but could not find a way.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fpklff3h9jKM9RR3ZLrJ?p=preview) for this.
HTML:

```
<tabset>
<tab id="a1" heading="Static 1">Static 111</tab>
<tab id="a2" heading="Static 2" ng-attr-active="{{nd}}">Static 222</tab>
</tabset>
```

JS:

```
$scope.nd = true;
```

ps:"tabs and their content should not be defined in a js file".

Comment: you have error in code, change this attribute and remove {{}} ng-attr-active="nd"

Comment: you are right, changed; my simple example works now, but still i could achieve the changing the tabs programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $scope.st = true;
        $scope.nd = false;

       $scope.goToSecond= function () {
            $scope.st = false;
            $scope.nd = true;
        };
        $scope.goToFirst= function () {
            $scope.nd = false;
            $scope.st = true;
        };
```

where

```
<tabset>
 <tab heading="Static title" ng-attr-active="st">"; </tab>
 <tab heading="Static 2" ng-attr-active="nd">"; </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 9):

I have just struggled for something on similar lines. In fact I almost erroneously drew the conclusion that static tabs cannot be changed programatically. But they can be.

```
 <tabset>
        <tab heading="Tab 1"  ng-attr-active="tabs[0].active">
              Tab 1 content
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Tab 2"  ng-attr-active="tabs[1].active">
              Tab 2 content
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Tab 3"  ng-attr-active="tabs[2].active">
              Tab 3 content
        </tab>
 </tabset>
 <button ng-click="make_tab3_active()">Make Tab 3 Active </button>
```

In Javascript you need

```
$scope.tabs = [{active: true}, {active: false}, {active: false}];
$scope.make_tab3_active = function() {
    $scope.tabs[2].active = true;
}
```

So just to point out - single variables will not do. They should be in an array - as outlined above. Although the docs give an example on similar lines, it's not clear because the 2 static tabs don't have active on them, and this can confuse you.

I spent a significant amount of time, before finding the answer on this thread: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611

Comment: Thanks, your answere helped me. I too was looking for such scenario in my application

Comment: Spot on, you are absolutely right.  If you are looking to change a tab via code, this will allow you to do it.